# How can I perform classification using a dictionary where each key is the label and each value is a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, recurrent-neural-network

Forgive me if this question has an obvious answer or if it has already been answered. I tried searching for an answer to the best of my ability but to no avail.

The problem here revolves around the idea that there is a python dictionary which contains keys that serve as labels and values which in this case are pandas dataframes that contain information for a timeseries. The goal for the program is to classify given an input dataframe which label must be applied to that dataframe according to the dictionary.

I understand that on the surface this may seem like a simple dictionary search based on values but the true problem lies in the fact that the input dataframe may or may not contain the same information as the dictionary. Hence, I plan on using machine learning -- specifically RNN (I am open to other ideas but this was what I was recommended over and over again) -- in order to perform this classification. But, due to my severe lack of knowledge about RNN algorithms as well as in reducing the dimensionality of a dataframe to serve as inputs, I am stuck. Any information or advice would be greatly appreciated.

More Information:

In order to get a closer look at what is happening, I have included some of my data below

```
        *A1    *A2    *B1    *B2

*0     *104    *258    *190    *284

*1     *102    *258    *186    *286

*2     *100    *254    *178    *286

*3      *98    *252    *170    *282

*4      *94    *248    *158    *278

*5      *90    *244    *148    *274
```

For context, in the table above, the rows 0 - 5 represents the change of the properties A1, A2, etc. over time. Here A1 and A2 can be thought about as X and Y values where they both describe the property of A. Hence, each row can be thought of as the position of properties split into its X and Y components. Note: the table has been reduced in size both in columns and rows just to show the main concept, I presume this shouldn’t be an issue except for processing power.

This table is loaded as a dataframe that is a value in the dictionary and has the label “ZERO”.  The overall dictionary has n items and the goal now would be to train a classifier which can take another dataframe as input and match it to a label. For example if I provided a dataframe like the one above but with slightly different values, how would I get the program to read out “ZERO” assuming that it is the most similar to the table above than any other table.

For more context about what the "slightly different values" above mean, I would like to provide the following table. This table is intended to be labeled as "ZERO" like the one above.

```
        *A1    *A2    *B1    *B2

*0     *107    *258    *192    *294

*1     *104    *259    *188    *296

*2     *103    *254    *180    *296

*3      *0      *0     *172    *292

*4      *97    *248    *160    *288

*5      *92    *244    *150    *284
```

The differences in the data is that the initial values may be slightly different and the changes between the different time stamps (rows 0-5) for each property may be slightly different from the original data (ie. the change between rows in the original dataframe may be 7 while in the input dataframe it may be 6, 7, or 8). But, the general trend in the data should be about the same in both the input and the matching dictionary dataframes. However, there are cases when the data entry will be zero indicating that there is no actual data in the row for that property. This is why I considered using RNN, but I understand that there are other methods of classification besides this and am open to any ideas/suggestions.

Thanks, VA

Please let me know if you need any further clarification or if the question doesn't make sense.

Edit 1: 
Added more information and context for the problem.

Edit 2: 
Added more information about the "slightly different values" in the dataframe

Edit 3: 
Rereading my question, I realized that I was talking about RNN and not KNN

Comment: This question needs more focus.

Comment: Agreed with Nicolas, remember: Consider you asking a busy colleague a question regarding an issue in which you are stuck. This seems too broad at the moment, and open to debate and discussion. Try to simplify your question to address the expected output and what is the issue you are having to achieve it. That might provide a better case for us to help you.

Comment: Hi Nicolas and Ivan, thank you for responding. Rereading my post, I agree that more information is need. Therefore, I have added more information above. I tried to be as clear as possible however, if there is still anything that is missing, please let me know. ~VA

Comment: What does it mean "slightly different values"? You need to define it precisely. You can calculate anything on two data frames and compare them; std, mean, thresholds, limits etc.

Comment: Hi kantal, I added more information about the "slightly different values." If there is still any confusion or any information missing, please let me know and I will try to add it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I just made a dictionary where the label was descriptive and the value was a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['2019-01-01',2,5],['2019-01-02',15,8],['2019-01-03',1,9],['2019-01-04',10,20],['2019-01-05',5,15]],columns = ['date','data1','data2'])
even = df[df['data1']%2==0]
odd= df[df['data1']%2==1]
dict1 = {'even':even,'odd':odd}
```

Comment: Hi James, thank you for your response. I have already created a dictionary based on this format. But, now I am struggling with how to create a classifier in order to determine what label should be applied to a new dataframe based on items in this dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

If there are few columns and they are not the same in each data frame, you can apply:

```
d= { (tuple(df.columns),df.index[0],df.index[-1]): df }
```

Comment: How would I go about doing this for a larger number of columns? What is the problem with this method for larger columns? Sorry, I am not well versed in dataframes yet. Thank you.

Comment: It's just about the execution speed of the lookup in the dictionary.